# Via Chrome devtools, how can I tell what element is actively scrolling?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

Long story short, Vue requires some trickery when debugging height and `@scroll` issues within componenets. The best call of action is to find what element is scrolling and move the scroll to the child, in my case.

So, how can I find what element is scrolling without countless additions/removals of event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element that you're scrolling on through the scroll event that gets passed to the scroll handler with `event.target`. I've included a snippet below which should hopefully help your case scenario.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    scrollHandler(ev) {
      console.log(ev.target.id);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app > div > div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100px;
  display:block;
}

h1 {
font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div :id="i" v-for="i in 5" :key="i" @scroll="scrollHandler">
      <h1>{{i}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```